# Sending RIL command on galaxy / nexus

Tags: android, java-native-interface, adb, ril

I wonder how can I send commands to rild - not rild-debug.
I have root and the program may be in c / java.

I tried radiooptions
( https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/android-hardware-ril/blob/master/rild/radiooptions.c ).

but radiooptions uses rild-debug and not rild.
I tried to change to SOCKET_NAME_RIL_DEBUG to SOCKET_NAME_RIL
but the program didn't do nothing..

There is any way I can send raw RIL commands ? (Maybe directly from adb ?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to do it with xposed:

we can find the class:

```
com.android.internal.telephony.RIL
```

find methods in it, and invoke them.

Answer (score 1):

Package:

```
com.android.internal.telephony
```

File:

```
com/android/internal/telephony/RIL.java
```

Method:

```
public void invokeOemRilRequestRaw(byte[] data, Message response)
```

To call the method, using code:

```
 import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

 ITelephony it = ITelephony.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
 it.invokeOemRilRequestRaw(oemReq, oemResp);
```

or using code(if possible):

```
import com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory;

((PhoneBase)PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone()).mCi.invokeOemRilRequestRaw(oemReq, oemResp);
```